# Is it possible to call a Maven target from a pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project `my.group.id:my.art.id` which has the following plugin defined:

```
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                            <type>remote</type>
                        </container>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>my.art.id</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>/my-root</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

In CLI, I deploy my WAR as following:

```
mvn cargo:deploy -Dcargo.user=... -Dcargo.password=...
```

I am now in the situation that I want to deploy `my.group.id:my.art.id` from another project `pom.xml`. This project is responsible for integration tests, I am spawning a *Dockerized* Tomcat container and need to deploy the WAR.

What is the best approach here?

1. Just copy/paste the plugin code as above
2. Execute Maven target `cargo:deploy -Dcargo.user=... -Dcargo.password=...` on `my.group.id:my.art.id`. Is it possible to call a Maven target from within a Maven build plugin? Will it spawn a child Maven process and wait for execution? Should I use the `exec-maven-plugin` plugin for this?

Comment: You can bind the plugin execution to a phase in the build. Then it is executed when you e.g. call `mvn install`.

Comment: In Docker container you put the resulting war into the tomcat and do not deploy it....

Comment: @khmarbaise Good suggestion, but for practical (and stupid) reasons, I currently need to deploy it instead of just putting the war in `/webapps`.

Comment: As JF Meier already suggest you need to bind the carge plugin to the life cycle...